# Deploy Play! application as executable jar

Tags: java, playframework

Is it possible to bundle Play! web application to executable jar instead of war?
Could it just be run on localhost at some port just like when using "play run" command? (without the need of installing play into system)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a WAR, you can use the embedded mode of the Winstone servlet container to get a stand-alone executable jar.  This is what Hudson does.