# Play framework rename Dpidfile.path property in Windows

Tags: playframework

Please can someone help, this is a question extending these topics:

[SO question setting up play dist on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088751/play-2-0-starting-as-windows-service-after-server-restart/15105099#15105099)

[SO Question changing Dpidfile.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088751/play-2-0-starting-as-windows-service-after-server-restart/15105099#15105099)

I have successfully got the service running on Windows using the first question. However I'm not sure how or where the Dpidfile.path setting needs to be placed? On Linux it would be ran as an arguement to the start script according to:

[Play production configuration document](https://github.com/freekh/Play20/wiki/ProductionConfiguration)

Any help much appreciated as always.
Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Not relevant now, fixed, there was some errors in the .bat file