# How do I fix server Oops error when deploying Play Framework 2.0 application as a Windows service?

Tags: deployment, playframework, windows-services

I was following the processes in this very helpful post:

[How do I run a Play Framework 2.0 application as a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120489/how-do-i-run-a-play-framework-2-0-application-as-a-windows-service)

when I ran into trouble in Step 9.  When I execute `runConsole.bat`, the service cycles between the **running** and **restarting** states.  The full log is here:

[wrapper.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21862473/dev/wrapper.log)

but what jumps out at me in the log are the following:

```
INFO|7268/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|Oops, cannot start the server.
INFO|7268/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

...

```
INFO|7268/0|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-168]
```

...

```
INFO|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:28|stopping process with pid/timeout 7268 45000
INFO|wrapper|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:30|process exit code: -1
```

...

```
INFO|7812/1|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:45|[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null
INFO|7812/1|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:45|Oops, cannot start the server.
INFO|7812/1|play.core.server.NettyServer|13-12-28 13:07:45|Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

repeats several times...

Answer (score 0):

Half way through writing this post, I realized that **before** step 9., you should terminate the **start.bat** script which you start up in step 6.  When I did this, `runConsole.bat` would execute normally without all the errors I list above.