# Running play Framework app as a service with YAJSW

Tags: playframework, yajsw

I'm trying to run a play framework app as a service with the [YAJSW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yajsw/) service wrapper as descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120489/how-do-i-run-a-play-framework-2-0-application-as-a-windows-service).

Every thing works fine until I start the service over "startService.bat". There is no problem if I run the "runConsole.bat".

It also doesn't start if I use the taskmanager, but it is installed.

I have no clue what is wrong. I hope someone can help me find the problem.

## startService.bat output

```
...
C:\my_app\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat>"java" -Xmx30m -Djna_tmpdir="C:\my_app\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\/../tmp" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "C:\my_app\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\/../wrapper.jar" -t "C:\my_app\yajsw-stable-11.11\bat\/../conf/wrapper.conf"        
YAJSW: yajsw-stable-11.11
OS   : Windows Server 2008 R2/6.1/x86
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.7.0_60/C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre/32
************* STARTING AppSoftware ***********************
Service AppSoftware NOT started
```

Comment: I changed the wrapper and solved this, If someone is interessted I will write an annwer by time.

Comment: Hi GiGo, adding an answer to your question will help others with similar problems.