# Deploying Play 2.3 on production

Tags: scala, playframework

I have developed a Scala/Play webapp and now I am trying to deploy it on production.
What is the recommended "best way" of doing that?

The [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production) mentions only runnig it from play console, which does not seem very robust (in case of machine restarts etc).

There are apporaches to wrap the app into a war file and deploy on Tomcat7 (e.g. play2war), but they do not seem to be actively developed (e.g. there is only beta support for 2.3, the plugin is not available from maven repo etc).

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you host the application on Windows then take a look at [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) which wraps the application in a Windows service that will keep it running, even after restarts.

If you run it on Linux then take a look at [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), which monitors the application and starts, restarts and stops it when needed.

See the following links for tutorials:

- [How do I run a Play Framework 2.0 application as a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120489/how-do-i-run-a-play-framework-2-0-application-as-a-windows-service)
- http://marcovanduijn.blogspot.nl/2011/08/run-play-framework-application-as.html
- http://blog.fgribreau.com/2013/09/how-to-make-play-framework-2-work-with.html

Comment: Nothing of that looks like a 'ready-to-go' solution that I'd like to use on production (like e.g. tomcat for Servlet-based webapps). Is there anything that the play community recommends as the 'first choice'?