# yajsw play framewok ssl error

Tags: ssl, playframework-2.2, jks, yajsw

I am using yajsw to deploy a play framework application on a windows machine as a windows service. I am using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120489/how-do-i-run-a-play-framework-2-0-application-as-a-windows-service/13565582#13565582) steps to install service. There is no problem with this method and working perfectly. However when I try to add a jks ssl file I get error. My start.bat file is something like that

```
    java -Dhttps.keyStore=XXX.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=YYY -Dhttp.port=disabled 
-Dhttps.port=9043 -cp "C:\Myapp\myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\lib\*" play.core.server.NettyServer
```

If I directly run this start.bat my jks works and I see ssl certificate on google chrome but If I try to make this a windows service when I run runConsole.bat and hit the url from google chrome it gives the stacktrace below and site is not visible

```
2015-02-19 18:58:59,187 - [ERROR] - from play in New I/O server boss #5 
Error loading HTTPS keystore from C:\Myapp\myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT\XXX.jks
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:78) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:77) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource$$anonfun$5.apply(AbstractManagedResource.scala:86) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:124) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:124) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:102) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:124) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireFor(AbstractManagedResource.scala:86) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.acquireAndGet(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:25) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.acquireAndGet(AbstractManagedResource.scala:48) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at resource.ManagedResourceOperations$class.foreach(ManagedResourceOperations.scala:45) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at resource.AbstractManagedResource.foreach(AbstractManagedResource.scala:48) ~[com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:77) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory$$anonfun$sslContext$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:69) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.sslContext$lzycompute(NettyServer.scala:69) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.sslContext(NettyServer.scala:68) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$PlayPipelineFactory.getPipeline(NettyServer.scala:51) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.registerAcceptedChannel(NioServerBoss.java:134) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.process(NioServerBoss.java:104) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

What is the difference between directly running start.bat and running it with yajsw? I am stucked.

Play framework version : 2.2.3
Yajsw version : 11.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem after two days. The problem is about a ,(comma) character.
You need to escape comma characters in your wrapper.conf file. It is documented as [below](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/YAJSW%20Configuration%20Parameters.html)

```
"," is used as list delimiter. If required you will have to escape it (eg write "\,")
```

I hope it avoids you from searching two days :)