# How do I run a Play Framework 2.4.4 application as a Windows service?

Tags: windows, playframework

I was trying to follow the steps described in

[How do I run a Play Framework 2.0 application as a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120489/how-do-i-run-a-play-framework-2-0-application-as-a-windows-service)

And i failed at step 5.
At first the service showed an error regarding the

> play.core.server.NettyServer

part of the script.
I changed it to

> play.core.server.ProdServerStart

But now I get an error running the start.bat saying

```
C:\GCS>java -cp "C:\GCS\lib\*" play.core.server.ProdServerStart
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:103)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:133)
        at play.api.ApplicationLoader$.createContext(ApplicationLoader.scala:91)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:50)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
        at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: application: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf, application.json: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.json, application.properties: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.properties
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleIncluder.fromBasename(SimpleIncluder.java:236)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.parseResourcesAnySyntax(ConfigImpl.java:132)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax(ConfigFactory.java:1024)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.java:238)
        at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.defaultApplication(ConfigFactory.java:519)
        at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$3.apply(Configuration.scala:75)
        at play.api.Configuration$$anonfun$3.apply(Configuration.scala:71)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:71)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:188)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:174)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:152)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleIncluder.fromBasename(SimpleIncluder.java:185)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:735)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable$ParseableResources.rawParseValue(Parseable.java:710)
        at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parseValue(Parseable.java:180)
        ... 16 more
```

I've looked for a solution for this everywhere, but couldn't find any.

I guess something else has changed in the way the dist is built since the original answer was given.

Anyone knows what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the config. on the classpath as well ie. depending on where your conf is, try something like the following (untested):

```
java -cp ".conf;.;lib/*" play.core.server.ProdServerStart
```